# Can't access localhost from Android Emulator, but on Simulator it's working

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, localhost, apache2

Hope anyone can help.

Why I can't access localhost (10.0.2.2) from Android Emulator, but when accessing from Simulator it's working.

I was try to edit server configuration as noticed from many tutorials, but still not working.

Here the screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a port number along with IP

> http:// 10.0.2.2:8080

Works perfect !

or

you can use IP of your pc which you can get by typing `ifconfig` in terminal.
Something like

> http://192.168.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my problem.

I try to change the port, so it working fine.

```
adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000
```

And now I can access my computer localhost on Android with accessing localhost:8000.

Answer (score -1):

I just got the same problem and the reason of why I could not connect to my machine was the setting of the emulator.

How to solve:

1. Open emulator.
2. Find the button with 3 dots, press it.
3. Go to "Settings" menu.
4. Disable "Use Android studio HTTP proxy settings".